# Re-render after drag and drop

Tags: javascript

If I drag and drop one element, then everything works fine, but if I add more elements, then everything does not work correctly.

I want to re-render all the elements after drag and drop. I don't care about their order, as long as they are in the right columns.

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong.

**[codepen](https://codepen.io/kvvprof/pen/XWZLavV)**

```
const newTasks = document.querySelector('.trello__body--new')
const inProgress = document.querySelector('.trello__body--in-progress')
const completed = document.querySelector('.trello__body--completed')
const columns = document.querySelectorAll('.trello__body')

let currentDragItemID = null

const tasks = [
    { id: 1, text: 'Learn JS', status: 'new' },
    { id: 2, text: 'Learn React', status: 'new' },
    { id: 3, text: 'Learn TypeScript', status: 'new' },
    { id: 4, text: 'Learn Node.js', status: 'new' },
    { id: 5, text: 'Learn Next.js', status: 'new' },
]

const dragStart = event => {
    currentDragItemID = parseInt(event.target.getAttribute('task-id'))
    event.target.classList.add('trello__item--hide')
}

const dragEnd = event => (event.target.className = 'trello__item')

const columnDragOver = event => event.preventDefault()

const columnDragEnter = event => event.target.classList.add('trello__body--active')

const columnDragLeave = event => event.target.classList.remove('trello__body--active')

const columnDragDrop = event => {
    const status = event.target.getAttribute('status')

    const updatedTasks = tasks.map(task => {
        if (task.id === currentDragItemID) {
            return { ...task, status: status }
        }
        return task
    })

    event.target.classList.remove('trello__body--active')
    render(updatedTasks)
}

function render(array) {
    document.querySelectorAll('.trello__item').forEach(elem => elem.remove())

    array.forEach(item => {
        const task = document.createElement('div')
        task.className = 'trello__item'
        task.innerHTML = item.text
        task.setAttribute('task-id', item.id)
        task.draggable = true

        switch (item.status) {
            case 'new':
                newTasks.append(task)
                break
            case 'in-progress':
                inProgress.append(task)
                break
            case 'completed':
                completed.append(task)
                break
            default:
                break
        }

        task.addEventListener('dragstart', dragStart)
        task.addEventListener('dragend', dragEnd)
    })
}

render(tasks)

columns.forEach(item => {
    item.addEventListener('dragover', columnDragOver)
    item.addEventListener('dragenter', columnDragEnter)
    item.addEventListener('dragleave', columnDragLeave)
    item.addEventListener('drop', columnDragDrop)
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issues can be found in the `columnDragDrop` function:

```js
const updatedTasks = tasks.map(task => {
    if (task.id === currentDragItemID) {
        return { ...task, status: status }
    }
    return task
})
```

---

Here you use `tasks` to alter the values, then you use that new array to render it: `render(updatedTasks)`.

This works fine, for the first time ;)

The second time this will run, you'll use `tasks` again, but thats the **original data**, not the data you've created on the previous drop.

So'll need to 'save' the result of that `map()`.

---

Easiest way is to change `tasks` from `const` to `let` and overwrite that variable each time so you'll use the most up-to-date data:

```js
tasks = tasks.map(task => {
    if (task.id === currentDragItemID) {
        return { ...task, status: status }
    }
    return task
})
```

Applying that logic gives us this demo:

```js
const newTasks = document.querySelector('.trello__body--new')
const inProgress = document.querySelector('.trello__body--in-progress')
const completed = document.querySelector('.trello__body--completed')
const columns = document.querySelectorAll('.trello__body')

let currentDragItemID = null

let tasks = [
    { id: 1, text: 'Learn JS', status: 'new' },
    { id: 2, text: 'Learn React', status: 'new' },
    { id: 3, text: 'Learn TypeScript', status: 'new' },
    { id: 4, text: 'Learn Node.js', status: 'new' },
    { id: 5, text: 'Learn Next.js', status: 'new' },
]

const dragStart = event => {
    currentDragItemID = parseInt(event.target.getAttribute('task-id'))
    event.target.classList.add('trello__item--hide')
}

const dragEnd = event => (event.target.className = 'trello__item')

const columnDragOver = event => event.preventDefault()

const columnDragEnter = event => event.target.classList.add('trello__body--active')

const columnDragLeave = event => event.target.classList.remove('trello__body--active')

const columnDragDrop = event => {
    const status = event.target.getAttribute('status')

    tasks = tasks.map(task => {
        if (task.id === currentDragItemID) {
            return { ...task, status: status }
        }
        return task
    })
 
    event.target.classList.remove('trello__body--active')
    render(tasks)
}

function render(array) {
    document.querySelectorAll('.trello__item').forEach(elem => elem.remove())

    array.forEach(item => {
        const task = document.createElement('div')
        task.className = 'trello__item'
        task.innerHTML = item.text
        task.setAttribute('task-id', item.id)
        task.draggable = true

        switch (item.status) {
            case 'new':
                newTasks.append(task)
                break
            case 'in-progress':
                inProgress.append(task)
                break
            case 'completed':
                completed.append(task)
                break
            default:
                break
        }

        task.addEventListener('dragstart', dragStart)
        task.addEventListener('dragend', dragEnd)
    })
}

render(tasks)

columns.forEach(item => {
    item.addEventListener('dragover', columnDragOver)
    item.addEventListener('dragenter', columnDragEnter)
    item.addEventListener('dragleave', columnDragLeave)
    item.addEventListener('drop', columnDragDrop)
})
```

```css
* {padding: 0; margin: 0; border: 0; }
*, *:before, *:after {-moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box; }
:focus, :active {outline: none; }
a {color: inherit; }
a:focus, a:active {outline: none; }
a, a:visited {text-decoration: none; }
a:hover {text-decoration: none; }
nav, footer, header, aside {display: block; }
html, body {height: 100%; width: 100%; font-size: 100%; line-height: 1; font-size: 14px; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; -moz-text-size-adjust: 100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; font-family: var(--font-family); font-weight: 400; }
input, button, textarea {font-family: inherit; }
textarea {resize: none; }
input::-ms-clear {display: none; }
button {cursor: pointer; }
button::-moz-focus-inner {padding: 0; border: 0; }
ul li {list-style: none; font-style: normal; }
img {vertical-align: top; }
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {font-size: inherit; font-weight: 400; }

/*--------------------*/

:root {--font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif; } 
body {display: flex; flex-direction: column; justify-content: center; align-items: center; background: #0f1217; } 
.container {max-width: 1000px; width: 100%; } 
.trello {display: flex; flex-direction: row; height: 100vh; } 
.trello__column {height: 100%; border: 1px solid #1d1f25; display: flex; flex-direction: column; justify-content: flex-start; flex: 1; } 
.trello__header {border-bottom: 1px solid #1d1f25; font-size: 22px; padding: 20px; font-weight: 600; color: #fff; text-align: center; background: #2e323b; } 
.trello__body {display: flex; flex-direction: column; justify-content: flex-start; overflow-y: auto; height: 100%; } 
.trello__item {background: #1d1f25; border: 1px solid #2e323b; color: #fff; padding: 20px; font-size: 18px; cursor: grab; opacity: 1; transition: 0.3s; width: 100%; } 
.trello__item--active {background: #cf4f40; } 
.trello__body--active {border: 1px solid #cf4f40; } 
.trello__item--hide {opacity: 0.2; transition: 0.3s; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <section class="trello">
    <div class="trello__column ">
      <div class="trello__header">New</div>
      <div class="trello__body trello__body--new" status="new">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="trello__column ">
      <div class="trello__header">In progress</div>
      <div class="trello__body trello__body--in-progress" status="in-progress"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="trello__column ">
      <div class="trello__header">Completed</div>
      <div class="trello__body trello__body--completed" status="completed"></div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```